# Dropdown menu of node titles that are made by a view

Tags: views, navigation

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that is a list of titles created by a view.

So I've made a view that creates a list of titles of a content type. I would like that list of titles to be in a dropdown menu.

I am using Superfish now, but I am not fully committed to it. If you can suggest a menu that will make this work I'm open to that.

I thought [Menu Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_views) would be an easy fix combined with Superfish. Menu Views has this to say

> By design, this module only provides basic HTML structure for
>   inserting a view into the menu system. It does not actually style your
>   [mega-]menu. If no styling exists in your theme or is not provided by
>   a contributed module, the view will appear next to your menu item
>   (which can often be a little confusing at first). It is up to the
>   theme or contributed module to actually style the view to appear
>   inside your menu. If the contributed theme or module implements drop
>   down menus, using CSS or JavaScript, a new child selector (li > .view)
>   must be included. The view can then be styled appropriately from
>   there.

I'm not sure where to start with the child selector.

Any advice on how to get the dropdown menu to display the node titles? Feel free to recommend any other modules that may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if or how the Superfish module integrates with Menu Views. Off the top of my head I kind of suspect it doesn't...

The simplest solution is to use CSS to hide the view except during the parent's :hover state. You can pick up a simple js to make that function in IE7 and below. There are of course plenty of other, mostly javascript or jQuery-based, solutions.

Comment: Damn, good idea, I'll try that today and get back with how it goes.

Comment: This still requires Menu Views and I'm not sure how to get the view created menu to display at all, :hover or not, properly.

Comment: Build out the view how you want it, then go to the menu item with Menu Views enabled and there should be an option to select the view you built.

Comment: You can use Menu Views or you can just make a php block and use module_invoke to programmatically include the block(s)/view(s) that you need. That's what we did on our latest project.